# How do I access the underlying DataTable in an ASP.NET GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datatable

I have a paginated GridView on an ASP.NET page. In the DataBound event of the GridView control, I am attempting to update the OnClick event of each cell in the row to window.open() a new page using a field in the underlying DataTable that is not displayed in the GridView. However, the GridView DataSource propety is null, as is the GridViewRow DataItem property. The GridView's DataKeys has a Count of 0. The paginated DataSet has 20 rows and is being rendered properly, I just can't find the underlying data to pull the ID needed for the window.open() call.

I have followed asp.net's guide when constructing my page:

1. [Creating a data access layer](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/introduction/creating-a-data-access-layer-cs)
2. [Creating a business access layer](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/introduction/creating-a-business-logic-layer-cs)
3. [Displaying Data with ObjectDataSource](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/basic-reporting/displaying-data-with-the-objectdatasource-cs)

So I have a DAL -> BLL -> ObjectDataSource -> GridView. The ID column is being hidden in the GridView:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="pdfdocuments" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="pdfods" PageSize="20" 
        ondatabound="pdfdocuments_DataBound">
        <PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="pdf_id" HeaderText="pdf_id" InsertVisible="False" 
                ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="pdf_id" Visible="False" />
...
        </Columns>
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#FFCC99" />
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

How do I access the pdf_id value in the underlying DataTable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try accessing GridView.DataSourceObject in the RowDataBound event.

Unless there is some requirement to use javascript window.open it is probably better to use an anchor tag with a target like the following code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="ODS1"
    OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="FieldName" DataNavigateUrlFields="FieldID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="somePage.aspx?id={0}" Target="_blank" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

If you have to execute JavaScript you can still do it without accessing the underlying DataSourceObject directly using a TemplateField:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="ODS1"
    OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <a href='javascript:window.open(<%# Eval("FieldID") %>);'><%#Eval("FieldName")%></a>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: The reason I am avoiding a separate column with a hyperlink in it is the horizontal screen real estate is a bit scarce, so I'd rather have the entire row clickable to open the associated document. Casting the DataSourceObject to DataTable or DataView results in a null value, so I am unsure how to get the data values out of DataSourceObject.

Comment: What I've done is used your first example and replaced all of the <asp:BoundField> entries with <asp:HyperLinkField> entries. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with D-Mac to use RowDataBound event. But instead of using GridView.DataSourceObject try to access the row's DataItem property.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    DataRowView rowView = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;
    if (rowView != null)
    {
        //Check if the execution reach this pont
        object pdf_id = rowView["pdf_id"];
    }
}
```

You can find an example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.dataitem.aspx)